# Render ChartJS graph within Browser control in C#.Net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, charts, webbrowser-control, internet-explorer-10

I'm having a Web Browser Control within a form and I'm opening HTML document containing [ChartJS](http://www.chartjs.org/) sample graph with dummy data. I'm on Windows 8 hence the browser control being used is IE10. Also, ChartJS renders charts using Canvas so that shouldn't be a problem with IE here.

Now, if I open document within Chrome or IE, it works fine. But opening it within browser control of the form doesn't render the chart and I'm getting script error saying `Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'`. Following is the actual markup I have along with required JS to render chart.

```
<canvas id="chart" width="800" height="400" style="margin: auto;"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript" src="chart.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var canvasObj = document.getElementById("chart").getContext("2d");
    var data = {
        labels : ["January","February","March","April","May","June","July"],
        datasets : [
            {
                strokeColor : "#5A90B3",
                pointColor : "#175177",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                data : [65,59,90,81,56,55,40]
            },
            {
                strokeColor : "#B55B5B",
                pointColor : "#7C2929",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                data : [28,48,40,19,96,27,100]
            },
            {
                strokeColor : "#529F54",
                pointColor : "#285F2A",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                data : [6,75,87,67,44,30,23]
            }
        ]
    };
    var lineChart = new Chart(canvasObj).Line(data, {
        datasetFill: false,
        bezierCurve : true
    });
</script>
```

Do I need to add any polyfills here? (which I doubt since IE10 is the browser frame C# should be using).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see this: [Web Browser Control – Specifying the IE Version](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version)
or in MSDN page [MSDN Library - Internet Feature Controls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee330730%28VS.85%29.aspx#browser_emulation)

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot! bit of a hacky though.